# Ayuda migrando a sentencias preparadas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

Saludos chicos estoy dando el paso de migrar mi conjunto de sentencias mysqli a sentencias preparadas con la finalidad de aumentar los niveles de seguridad de mi aplicativo web, pero no se como hacerlo, de hecho si puedo pasarlos a PDO lo haria aun cuando no me gusta porque no lo comprendo muy bien, pero seria una manera de mantener mi aplicativo seguro y a su vez de yo adaptarme a esas nuevas tecnicas.
La conexión a mi BD la hago asi:

```
     $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'clave', 'mi_bd');
        mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Indagando creo que via PDO debe hacerse asi:

```
    $db->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mi_bd', 'usuario', 'clave');
```

Pero no se si es de esa manera que debo hacerlo
Tres de de las funciones son:

```
    // LISTAR BANCO DESTINO
<?php
        function banco_destino(){
            global $db;
            $query = "SELECT * FROM banco_destino";
            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);


            while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$valores['banco_destino'].'">'.$valores['banco_destino'].'</option>';
            }
        }

    function ejecutar_editar_mensajeria(){
      global $db;

    $rowid      = ($_REQUEST['id']);  
    $contenido  = ($_REQUEST['contenido']);
    $asunto  = ($_REQUEST['asunto']);


      $sql = "UPDATE mensajes SET
      contenido = '$contenido', asunto = '$asunto'
      WHERE id = '$rowid'";
      if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
        $_SESSION['editar_mensajeria']  = "Se ha Actualizado el contenido de manera correcta..!!<br>";

     } else {
      $_SESSION['editar_mensajeria']  = "NO SE PUEDE ACTUALIZAR..!!";
        echo "Un Error ha ocurrido: " . mysqli_error($db);
        //mysqli_close($db);
     }
    }

    function procesar_enviar_comentario(){
        global $db, $logo, $footer_correo;
        $user= $_REQUEST['usua'];
        $comentario= $_REQUEST['comentario'];
        echo $user .
        $comentario;

        $query = "INSERT INTO comentario (id, user, comentario) 
    VALUES(null, '$user', '$comentario')";
        //mysqli_query($db, $query);
        //$resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($db, $query) or mysqli_error($db); 
        if (mysqli_query($db, $query)){
        $_SESSION['comentario']  = "Se ha registrado su comentario y en breve figurara en el carrusel de comentarios.<br>";
      } else {
        echo mysqli_error($db);
    }
    } ?>
```

Logicamente tengo muchas otras sentencias en mi aplicativo pero creo que si alguien me ayuda con estas 3 function yo creo poder hacer la migracion de mis otros querys o sentencias.

Comment: Creo que es mejor que decidas primero con qué te vas a quedar, si con PDO o con mysqli. Desde mi experiencia, PDO es mucho más fácil que mysqli, y sobre todo facilita algunas cosas complejas, a diferencia de mysqli. Luego, si te decides por mysqli de todos modos, recomendaría que en vez del estilo procedural, adoptes el estilo orientado a objetos. Es mucho más comprensible y menos *verboso*.

Comment: en los ejemplo que coloque puedo pasarlos a consulta preparada usando mysqli..? lo que quiero es tratar de brindarle seguridad a mi codigo de inyeccion SQL..!

Comment: Veo que en la consulta preparada las variables las declaro luego del query y me he vuelto un ocho, he intentado hacerlo solo pero me da errores nuevos para mi y que no logro hacer que corra de manera correcta..!